# Run command ant_compile in command prompt and getting build failed error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ant, testng

Run command ant_compile in command prompt and getting below error------ Need help on this

```
F:\Frameworks\DDF>ant compile  
Buildfile: F:\Frameworks\DDF\build.xml  
setPath:  
initialization:  
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource testngtasks. It could not be found.  
clear:  
   [delete] Deleting directory F:\Frameworks\DDF\build  
compile:  
     [echo] Creating directory...  
    [mkdir] Created dir: F:\Frameworks\DDF\build  
     [echo] Suite class path Is ------:  
     [echo] compiling...  
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\build.xml:57: warning: 'includeant  
runtime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds  
    [javac] Compiling 9 source files to F:\Java-sonal\DataDrivenFramework\build  
    [javac]  
    [javac]           WARNING  
    [javac]      
   [javac]   location: class SuiteOneCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteOne\SuiteOneCaseTwo.java:98: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @AfterMethod    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterMethod    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteOneCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteOne\SuiteOneCaseTwo.java:122: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @DataProvider    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteOneCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteOne\SuiteOneCaseTwo.java:130: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @AfterTest    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterTest    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteOneCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoBase.java:19: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @BeforeSuite    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class BeforeSuite    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoBase    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseOne.java:31: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @BeforeTest    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class BeforeTest    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseOne    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseOne.java:58: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @Test(dataProvider="SuiteTwoCaseOneData")    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseOne    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseOne.java:97: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @AfterMethod    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterMethod    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseOne    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseOne.java:121: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @DataProvider    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseOne    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseOne.java:129: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @AfterTest    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterTest    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseOne    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseTwo.java:31: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @BeforeTest    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class BeforeTest    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseTwo.java:58: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @Test(dataProvider="SuiteTwoCaseTwoData")    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseTwo.java:97: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @AfterMethod    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterMethod    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseTwo.java:121: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @DataProvider    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseTwo.java:129: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]     @AfterTest    
    [javac]      ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterTest    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\TestSuiteBase\SuiteBase.java:22: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]             Add_Log = Logger.getLogger("rootLogger");    
    [javac]                       ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   variable Logger    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteBase    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\TestSuiteBase\SuiteBase.java:23: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]             PropertyConfigurator.configure("F:\\Frameworks\\DDF\\src\\com\\stta\\xslt\\log4j.properties");    
    [javac]             ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   variable PropertyConfigurator    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteBase    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:160: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                                     XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i+1);    
    [javac]                                     ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class XSSFRow    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:166: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                                                     XSSFCell cell =row.getCell(j);    
    [javac]                                                     ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class XSSFCell    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:172: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]             cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);    
    [javac]    
         ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   variable Cell    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:268: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                             XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);    
    [javac]                             ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class XSSFCell    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:269: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                             cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);    
    [javac]   symbol:   variable Cell    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:277: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                     XSSFRow Row = ws.getRow(rowNumber);    
    [javac]                     ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class XSSFRow    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\utility\Read_XLS.java:278: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                     XSSFCell cell = Row.getCell(colNumber);    
    [javac]                     ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class XSSFCell    
    [javac]   location: class Read_XLS    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteOne\SuiteOneCaseTwo.java:64: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]             s_assert = new SoftAssert();    
    [javac]                            ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class SoftAssert    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteOneCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteOne\SuiteOneCaseTwo.java:70: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                     throw new SkipException("DataToRun for row number "+DataSet+" Is No Or Blank. So Skipping Its Execution.");    
    [javac]                               ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class SkipException    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteOneCaseTwo    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoBase.java:34: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                     throw new SkipException(SuiteName+"'s SuiteToRun Flag Is 'N' Or Blank. So Skipping Execution Of "+SuiteName);    
    [javac]                               ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class SkipException    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoBase    
    [javac] F:\Frameworks\DDF\src\com\stta\SuiteTwo\SuiteTwoCaseOne.java:51: error: cannot find symbol    
    [javac]                     throw new SkipException(TestCaseName+"'s CaseToRun Flag Is 'N' Or Blank. So Skipping Execution Of "+TestCaseName);    
    [javac]                               ^    
    [javac]   symbol:   class SkipException    
    [javac]   location: class SuiteTwoCaseOne    
    [javac] 100 errors    
    [javac] 1 warning    

BUILD FAILED    
F:\Frameworks\DDF\build.xml:57: Compile failed; see the compiler    
 error output for details.    
Total time: 1 second    
F:\Frameworks\DDF>
```

Comment: You've simply posted up your compiler output, with no indication of what the code is.... The error here is pretty obvious you're missing at least one 3rd party library. As to which very difficult to tell. This is a compilation error nothing to do with TestNg or Selenium. Could I suggest to publish what your code and build files look like. This it might be possible to reproduce the problem

Comment: You missed TestNg in your classpath, you just attached compiler output please share build script/structure for solution.